# can't use condition greater than in Apache Velocity

Tags: java

I use Apache velocity Email template for sent email but can't check condition`#if ($book == 0) or #if ($book > 0)`

Comment: Is this the only velocity logic you have in the template, or are there other velocity directives that do work?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean you can't check condition. You can very well do that. See this [doc](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.5/user-guide.html#conditionals)

Comment: yes I read already but the type of '$book' variable is Double. Could this be the root cause?

Comment: what is the error you are seeing? Is it that its not going in if block and going to else block? Can you log the value of book before condition check?

Comment: doesn't go to any block